# How can I trigger the com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION Google Now action for testing?

Tags: android, google-search, google-search-platform

I am building an Android app and would like to integrate the ability to search using voice with Google Now Actions as described in this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html). Before I push the app to the Play Store, is there a way to test my intent filter (`com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION`), search expression handling, etc.? I've followed the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Search) and included the intent filter as below:

```
<activity android:name=".SearchActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can use `adb` activity manager to trigger the activity using the syntax below:

> adb shell am start -a **com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION**
>   -e query **foo** <**app package name here**>

Comment: Hi Jarek! I just saw your GoogleDevelopers talk "Implementing Freemium with Google play In-app Billing API" on YouTube. I think I found some severe problems with the docs and logic-flow of the Billing API v3, but I can't get a hold of anyone at Google about this. Could I ask you to take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921789/working-around-api-purchase-logic-flaws-for-consumables-in-google-plays-billing and forward it to the right person at Google? Thank you!

Comment: I can not start with query constant space, for example, `-e query incorrect record`, do you have any suggestion?