# Cannot receive search queries from Google Now

Tags: android, google-search

I am trying to connect Google Now `SEARCH_ACTION` with my searchable activity using this piece of code in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>`

I am following instructions on http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/the-fastest-route-between-voice-search.html and https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#SearchOnApp.

This is just not working. The search from Google Now is not launching my app. I have verified that:

1. This works for Eat 24 app, confirming that there's no issue with right version of OS/Google app/Locale.
2. I can launch app from inside my app and receive typed search queries, confirming that my `SearchableActivity` code doesn't have any issues.

Anyone has gotten this to work? Could you please let me know what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Well... looks like the app needs to be published on Play Store:
https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/afSRdDQiy1N - look for comments by Jarek Wilkiewicz. Going to try this next.

Comment: that's true. You can test your app first using adb, more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824604/how-can-i-trigger-the-com-google-android-gms-actions-search-action-google-now-ac